# Custom Rails cache and associations - overwriting ActiveRecord.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write a custom ActiveRecord cache, just for `find_by_id` right now.
To do that I want to overwrite the find method, when just a single int is given use my cache, otherwise use the default implementation.

```
class X < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.find(*args)
        return XCache[args[0]] if args.size == 1 && args[0].is_a?(Numeric)
        return super.find(*args)
    end
end
```

Everything works find except for the case of an association I have with other instances of X, e.g. a parent-child relationship:

```
has_many :x_children
has_many :children, :class_name => "X", :through => :x_children
```

When I call `X.find(1).children` I get an `Enumerator` instead of an `Array`, which is bad since I sometimes use the [] operator.

Even using the enumerator doesn't work well - when iterating the last entry I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for :all:Symbol
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Further explanation:

XCache is just a class that caches instances of ActiveRecord.
A simplistic implementation can be

```
class XCache
    @@cache = {}
    def self.[id]
        return @@cache[id] ||= X.find(id)
    end
end
```

(A more advanced implementation can include expiration time, Memcached etc., and a more generic solution can support multiple model classes).

I don't think my problem is related to the cache implementation (but I might be wrong)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here? A general-purpose library or a solution to a specific problem?

Comment: Could you explain what the `XCache` is? I search on the internet, but did not find anything. If you have implemented on your own (and if it is not too much code), just add that code to your question.

Comment: don't know if it helps, but the fact is that [Active Record caches associated records by default](http://www.kickasslabs.com/2009/04/23/rails-gotcha-activerecord-caches-associated-records-by-default/)

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen there is a lot of hidden complexity here. You could look into the [cache-money](https://github.com/ngmoco/cache-money) gem, these guys have spent a lot of effort figuring it out.

Other gems to look at: [simple_cacheable](https://github.com/flyerhzm/simple_cacheable)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but... This is what find looks like on the inside:

```
  def find(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    validate_find_options(options)
    set_readonly_option!(options)

    case args.first
      when :first then find_initial(options)
      when :last  then find_last(options)
      when :all   then find_every(options)
      else             find_from_ids(args, options)
    end
  end
```

You don't need to overload "find", but "find_from_ids"

That will let you leave alone all the other ways that find is used and just target your own usage.Given that enumerators are what are returned by find(:all)... it might help your situation (or might not).

The othr possibility is... does Xcache return just a single ActiveRecord or is it possible that it sometimes returns a set... or even an empty set?

Perhaps you could try variations on:

```
def self.find(*args)
    if args.size == 1 && args[0].is_a?(Numeric)
       rval = XCache[args[0]]
       return rval if rval.present?
    end
    super.find(*args)
end
```